# How to print the value in JSON flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON with some keys and values, I want to access the value in my widget, but I don't understand how. I created a class for my data, but how do I access the value?

My class:

```
class PersonKpi {
  late Lc lc;
  late Fc fc;
  late Revenue revenue;
  late Fc checklist;
  late Persondata persondata;
  late Total total;

  PersonKpi(
      {
        required this.lc,
        required this.fc,
        required this.revenue,
        required this.checklist,
        required this.persondata,
        required this.total
      }
  );

  PersonKpi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    lc = (json['lc'] != null ? new Lc.fromJson(json['lc']) : null)!;
    fc = (json['fc'] != null ? new Fc.fromJson(json['fc']) : null)!;
    revenue =
    (json['revenue'] != null ? new Revenue.fromJson(json['revenue']) : null)!;
    checklist =
    (json['checklist'] != null ? new Fc.fromJson(json['checklist']) : null)!;
    persondata = (json['persondata'] != null
        ? new Persondata.fromJson(json['persondata'])
        : null)!;
    total = (json['total'] != null ? new Total.fromJson(json['total']) : null)!;
  }
}

class Lc {
  late int percent;
  late String color;
  late int weight;
  late double totalWeight;
  late double totalRubForPerson;

  Lc({
    required this.percent,
    required this.color,
    required this.weight,
    required this.totalWeight,
    required this.totalRubForPerson
  });

  Lc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    percent = json['percent'];
    color = json['color'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    totalWeight = json['total_weight'];
    totalRubForPerson = json['total_rub_for_person'];
  }
}
```

And my JSON:

> {
> "lc": {
> "percent": 100.4,
> "color": "yellow",
> "weight": 30,
> "total_weight": 32.51,
> "total_rub_for_person": 7.5
> }
> }

How print Lc.percent?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this and if it from API call then you decode your data

```
void main() {
 var mapdata = { "lc": { "percent": 100.4, "color": "yellow", "weight": 30, "total_weight": 32.51, "total_rub_for_person": 7.5 } };
  // for data convert 
  //var data = jsonDecode(mapdata.data);
  print(PersonKpi.fromJson(mapdata).lc.percent); // 100

}


class PersonKpi {
  Lc lc;

  PersonKpi({this.lc});

  PersonKpi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    lc = json['lc'] != null ? new Lc.fromJson(json['lc']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.lc != null) {
      data['lc'] = this.lc.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Lc {
  double percent;
  String color;
  int weight;
  double totalWeight;
  double totalRubForPerson;

  Lc(
      {this.percent,
      this.color,
      this.weight,
      this.totalWeight,
      this.totalRubForPerson});

  Lc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    percent = json['percent'];
    color = json['color'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    totalWeight = json['total_weight'];
    totalRubForPerson = json['total_rub_for_person'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['percent'] = this.percent;
    data['color'] = this.color;
    data['weight'] = this.weight;
    data['total_weight'] = this.totalWeight;
    data['total_rub_for_person'] = this.totalRubForPerson;
    return data;
  }
}
```